# How to open a different program if a specific program is closed in batch script?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I need to close a few useless background processes with tskill (since I use only XP Home SP3), specifically Firefox, Notepad, Winamp, explorer.exe, and 2 to 3 would-be useless Services first.
Then open a mid-spec game of my choice (one per copy of the batch file) like Warcraft 3.
The batch file should wait for me to close that game, and if I do so, the script will re-launch explorer.exe, and end itself so that I can re-run any copy the batch file without problems.
I'll only use this script for one user, BTW [which is my game-dedicated account].

I tried this sample code, but it goes wrong on other uses but the first time:

```
tskill mspaint
start "Notepad" "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (start "Paint" "C:\WINDOWS\system32\mspaint.exe")
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

`start` has a `/WAIT` switch that waits for the program to end:

```
start /WAIT "Notepad" "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe"
```

This way, the batch file won't continue right away, but after the program has been closed.

Comment: Oh, I see... That saves me a lot of work! Thanks a lot dude. :) I'll just have to test on re-running explorer.exe to make sure it works as desired.